# What is this extension of my Mango Tree? Is it weed or is it helpful for it?

Tags: identification, trees, weed-control, weeds, tropical

My 3 year old Mango Tree has some kind of extension on it. What is it?
Should I remove it or let it stay?[image: this is the extension image]

Comment: Good question & illustration; if could include an overall illustration, and closer illustration of the feature & of feature tops, feature size, if feature seems to be growing _on_ the branch or if feature seems to be growing _into_ the branch, overall tree height & leaf size, and the region, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Comment: A ruler or some measuring tape in the picture not only adds some cool sciency note ;-)

Comment: Epiphytes, including orchids, are common on mango: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=epiphyte+mango&t=ftas&ia=images&iax=images

Comment: I wonder if this could be a type of growth called "[witches broom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch's_broom)." Witches broom is not a separate plant, rather it grows directly off of the original tree. It's usually a sign of disease.